# Hello World in KotlinJS failing with Kotlin is not defined

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a Kotlin file called `Main.kt`

```
package com.ahp.mui

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("...")
    println("Hello World")

}
```

Project is setup as a KotlinJS project.

Once I hit compile, I see the following files being generated:

```
target/production/ahp-mui/ahp-mui.js
target/production/ahp-mui/ahp-mui.js.map
target/production/ahp-mui/ahp-mui.meta.js
```

The main generated file contains:

```
(function (Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var _ = Kotlin.defineRootPackage(null, /** @lends _ */ {
    com: Kotlin.definePackage(null, /** @lends _.com */ {
      ahp: Kotlin.definePackage(null, /** @lends _.com.ahp */ {
        mui: Kotlin.definePackage(null, /** @lends _.com.ahp.mui */ {
          main_kand9s$: function (args) {
            Kotlin.println('...');
            Kotlin.println('Hello World');
          }
        })
      })
    })
  });
  Kotlin.defineModule('ahp-mui', _);
  _.com.ahp.mui.main_kand9s$([]);
}(Kotlin));
```

Now I include that file in `index.html` sitting in the root directory:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    TESTING


    <script type="text/javascript" src="target/production/ahp-mui/ahp-mui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now serving that `index.html` file directly via IntelliJ (`http://localhost:63342/ahp-wui/ahp-mui/index.html?_ijt=n55ajlpfutv6b22n56d59jv1rn`), I see that the `Kotlin` paramater is not defined.

```
ahp-mui.js:16Uncaught ReferenceError: Kotlin is not defined
```

Am I doing this correctly? Should I be importing anything else that will include the missing `Kotlin` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ should have plopped a Kotlin standard library `.js` file somewhere. This was configured when you created the project. You must include this in the HTML file before your compiled `.js` file.

Comment: Switching on `Copy library runtime files` generated a `kotlin.js` and a `stdlib.meta.js`.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert Include Kotlin.js in the HTML file.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the kotlin.js file via maven ?